# Left Align the secondary text on Widgets.Welcome

Tags: vala

Is there a way to right align the secondary text on the welcome widget. I have a rather longish secondary text (attached screenshot) and the text will look better if the left margin is aligned rather then the centering of the text.

Also is there a way to break the text into two paragraphs.
Here is the code snippet, I use - standard way to create the welcome widget.

```
Granite.Widgets.Welcome welcome = new Granite.Widgets.Welcome (
    NuttyApp.Constants.PRIMARY_TEXT_FOR_DISCLAIMER,   
    NuttyApp.Constants.SECONDARY_TEXT_FOR_DISCLAIMER
);
```

The complete code is [here](https://github.com/babluboy/nutty/blob/260d8ea4db450af1c297a9f43d99301fb121b241/src/window.vala#L28) on GitHub.

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be out of luck here. `Granite.Widgets.Welcome` does not have an API for that.

Here's an approach that might still work: `Granite.Widgets.Welcome` is a subclass of `Gtk.Bin` containing a `Gtk.Grid`. To get at the label you should first get the grid using `Granite.Widgets.Welcome.get_child ()` and then search for the label inside that grid using `Gtk.Grid.get_children ()` which returns a list of all children. In that list you should find your desired label. To align the text to the left, just set `that_label.justify = Gtk.Justification.LEFT`.

**However**, you really should not do this. `Granite.Widgets.Welcome` is not meant for this purpose. It should contain short headings and everything  that goes further should not be included here.

I would suggest using a `Gtk.Dialog` with a "Do not show again" tick box  that pops up on startup instead.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, will try that. It seems logical. I did have a dialogue before with “remember the decision” but the welcome looks a better experience since I have a URL as part of the text and granite link urls with the icon looks so much better...

Comment: Just in case someone else needs this, here is the code snippet: //Format welcome secondary text
  Grid welcome_grid = (Grid) welcome.get_child ();
  GLib.List<weak Gtk.Widget> welcome_widgets = welcome_grid.get_children ();
  foreach(Widget aWelcomeWidget in welcome_widgets){
   debug(aWelcomeWidget.get_path().to_string());
   //grab the secondary text label
  if(aWelcomeWidget.get_path().to_string().contains("GtkLabel") &&
      aWelcomeWidget.get_path().to_string().contains("h2"))
   {
       ((Label)aWelcomeWidget).justify = Gtk.Justification.LEFT;
       break;
   }
      
  }